# Integrate facebook ads tracking ID on react native

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, mobile

I have a react native application built with expo. 
Now I am going to integrate facebook ads tracking ID in it.
In other words, I want to track ads that people click on it installing and opening the app. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: No, I haven't.
If you found a solution, please share it with me.

Comment: Yes, I found a solution, firebase dynamic link is what we want https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage